# Track Vget download progress

Tags: java

How do you track the download progress of Vget?

```
String url = textField.getText();
String path = fpath;

VGet v = new VGet(new URL(url), new File(path));
//Should track v.download(); download progress
v.download();
```

Comment: What is `VGet`? Do you have a link to the JavaDoc of this package? (Have you read it?)

Comment: @janos https://github.com/Litarvan/vget

Answer (score 0):

It show's it on their github page how to do it.

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (now - 1000 > last) {
    last = now;

    String parts = "";

    for (VideoFileInfo dinfo : dinfoList) {
        SpeedInfo speedInfo = getSpeedInfo(dinfo);
        speedInfo.step(dinfo.getCount());

        List<Part> pp = dinfo.getParts();
        if (pp != null) {
            // multipart download
            for (Part p : pp) {
                if (p.getState().equals(States.DOWNLOADING)) {
                    parts += String.format("part#%d(%.2f) ", p.getNumber(),
                            p.getCount() / (float) p.getLength());
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("file:%d - %s %.2f %s (%s)", dinfoList.indexOf(dinfo),
                videoinfo.getState(), dinfo.getCount() / (float) dinfo.getLength(), parts,
                formatSpeed(speedInfo.getCurrentSpeed())));
    }
```

For the full code check out their github page [here](https://github.com/Litarvan/vget)